# Margin calculation in MDX

Tags: excel, mdx

We have our BI sales cubes connected to Excel and build our reports by dragging predefined measures to pivot tables. Since the predefined measures don't cover my needs I have created my own calculations in MDX or as Excel formulas next to the pivot tables when it has been to complicated for me to set up in MDX. I want to avoid the latter but my MDX skills are low. It would be great with support to help converting this measure from Excel formula to MDX.

The purpose of the measure is to see how much each product group contributes to the change in the total margin (not the product groups margin) compared to last year. This is to quickly identify why the margin is changing and which product manager to contact for more in depth analysis.

I was unsure how to describe the formulas used so I took a screenshot of the Excel. Column A to F is representing the pivot and G is my formula. In the formula shown I am calculating how much the change in demand and profit since last year for shirts is affecting the total margin. (I wasn't able to post the image due to lack of reputation but here is the link)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pGkS.png

Explanation of the fields:

```
Demand = Demand this year
Demand LY = Demand last year
Profit = Profit this year
Profit LY = Profit last year
Margin = Margin this year (Profit/Demand)
```

I would greatly appreciate help! Let me know what more information I need to add and I'll be right on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PrevMember method in order to get the last year member. For example:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[Demand LY] as
([Date].[Year].PrevMember,[Measures].[Demand])

Member [Measures].[Profit LY] as
([Date].[Year].PrevMember,[Measures].[Profit])

Member [Measures].[Margin] as
[Measures].[Profit] / [Measures].[Demand]

Member [Measures].[Margin LY] as
[Measures].[Profit LY] / [Measures].[Demand LY]

Member [Measures].[Margin Progress] as
[Measures].[Margin] - [Measures].[Margin LY]

select
{[Measures].[Demand],[Measures].[Profit],[Measures].[Demand LY],[Measures].[Profit LY],[Measures].[Margin],[Measures].[Margin LY],[Measures].[Margin Progress]} on 0
from [YourCube]
where [Date].[Year].[2017]
```

Edit: You may apply the following code in order to calculate percentage share:

```
[Measures].[Margin] / ([Product].[Product].[All],[Measures].[Margin])
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but if I understand your answer it is not solving my problem. I already have measures comparing this years margin to last years margin. What I want to achieve is to see how much each product group contributes to the change of margin on the total sales (if we sum up column G in my screenshot then it will sum up to the difference in margin on the total sales compared to last year.

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer, let me know it if it's what you wished.